# Why doesn't this C# code compile when using named parameters?

Tags: c#-4.0

Baffled.

```
class Test
{
    void Main()
    {
        F(() => "");                // ok
        F(named: () => "");         // 'T' cannot be inferred from the usage!
        F<string>(() => "");        // ok
        F<string>(named: () => ""); // ok
    }

    void F<T>(Func<T> named) { }
}
```

Could someone tell me why the second call to F fails to compile?

(Note that this is a significantly stripped down example, which is why it seems synthetic. In the real case I came across, there are some default parameters before 'named' and so the named parameter is required. And so, apparently is explicit specification of 'T' by the caller.)

Comment: seems like an inadequacy in the compiler's delegate type inference.

Comment: Sounds likely. And if you make that comment into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like an inadequacy in the compiler's delegate type inference...sorry I can't offer more.

Comment: Why the downvote? No one else cared to answer and the author stated "Sounds likely. And if you make that comment into an answer I'll accept it.".